# Routing in ListView not working

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm facing trouble with routing in mys ListView. Routing seems not to work or to be very slow.

Here is the "html" view :

```
<ActionBar [title]="'TITLE' | translate" >
  <ActionItem [text]="'SETTINGS' | translate " (tap)="settings()"
    android.systemIcon="ic_menu_share_holo_dark"
    ios.systemIcon="9"
    ios.position="right">
  </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="auto, auto, *">

  <SearchBar [(ngModel)]="search" [hint]="'SEARCH' | translate" row="0"
    (submit)="searchSubmit()"
    (clear)="searchClear()"
    #searchFilter (keyup) = "0"
  ></SearchBar>

  <Button **(tap)="select(null)"** row="1" ></Button>

  <!--<ListView [items]="groceryList" row="1" class="small-spacing"> -->
  <ListView [items]="signalList | signalFilter:search " row="2" class="small-spacing" [class.visible]="listLoaded">
    <template let-item="item">
      <GridLayout rows="*"  columns="50px, *, auto"   >
          <Image col="0" [src]="item.image | signalImage " stretch="none"
              horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignement="center"
              ></Image>
          <StackLayout col="1" **(tap)="select(item)"** >
            <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing" class="list-title"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item.description | slice:0:150" class="list-description" textwrap="true" ></Label>
          </StackLayout>
          <Button col="2" text="See" **(tap)="select(item)"** ></Button>
        </GridLayout>
    </template>
  </ListView>

  <ActivityIndicator [busy]="isLoading"
        [visibility]="isLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapse'"
          row="1"
          horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
  </ActivityIndicator>
```

I put some tap on different objects :
- On a button under my search bar (just for test)
- On the stacklayout,
- On a button right to my stacklayout.

Here is the code :

```
select(signal : Signal) {
      console.dump(signal);
      // For the debug ...
      let id:string = "2";
      //if(signal != null) { id = signal.id; }
      this._router.navigate(["View", { id: id }]);
  }
```

When I tap on the first button : everythings goes fine and quick. If I tap on the others possibilities : routing does not work. I've to do another event like tying in the search bar to makes things working.

Here my package.json :

```
{
  // [...]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.2.0",
    "nativescript-ng2-translate": "^1.1.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^2.2.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.10.4",
    "babel-types": "6.11.1",
    "babylon": "6.8.4",
    "filewalker": "0.1.3",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
 }
}
```

Ps : I've noticed that I've two packages.json. One in my root project folder and a second one in my app project folder. They seems not to be synchronised. May this a be trouble ? Which one is finally used ? In this post, I show you the project one.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is a problem with the way you are using the router. In NativeScript Angular2 project you could create `RouterConfig` object, which maps paths to components or to use `router-outlet`, You could review [this](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/navigation-angular.html#navigation) article, where have been described how to do navigation in NativeScript application using Angular. In regard to problem you could also review my sample project in [this](https://github.com/tsonevn/NGNavigationRtConf) repo

Comment: I changed my code. But I'm still facing an issue : if I use a button outside the list and come back : no problem. But If I do the same in the list and come back : the ngInit method of my list is not called ... So my page is empty ...

Comment: You could try to load your ListView Content in the `constructor` or on ListView `onloaded`  event. This should solve your problem with the navigation and your ListView. In regard to that I upgraded my sample project and added ListView on the second page.

Comment: Not working also ... And based from what I read, It should be done on ngOnInit. Why is it not called as it used to be ? I think that I have to restart my project based on change on the doc ... Thanks for your help.

Comment: This problem might be caused by the fact that some of the layouts have not been loaded on `ngOnInit` and in this case you would not be allowed to load your content in the listView. You could also try to do that on `ngAfterViewInit`. However you could also review the article for NativeScript ListView - http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html

Comment: In fact I think somethings goes wrong since my last npm update and nothing is working as it used to be ... Again thanks for your help but I think I've to restart my project.

Comment: For info, I switch back to native-script 0.1.1 and angular 2?rc1 and everything works fine again ...